# recursive sql query for multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql, categories

I have a query like below which pulls category data from two tables,

```
SELECT pc.productCategoryId, pcs.parentCategoryId, pc.categoryId
FROM productCategory AS pc
LEFT JOIN productCategories AS pcs ON pcs.categoryId = pc.categoryId
WHERE pc.productId =110
ORDER BY pc.categoryId
```

and this is the result

```
productCategoryId parentCategoryId categoryId Ascending
225               0                1
773               1                1283
773               132              1283
774               1283             10314
```

but this is the desired result

```
productCategoryId parentCategoryId categoryId Ascending
    225               0                1
    773               1                1283
    774               1283             10314
```

my goal is to keep the records with the matching following parent category ids, so the third one should be taken out somehow.
 i mean every previous records categoryid should match next one's parentcategoryId

Comment: I don't believe it is entirely clear what you are asking with "my goal is to keep the records with the matching following parent category ids".

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. Unless there is a very limited max number of levels of parent / child relationships then you will need to code multiple queires and loop around them in code, or redesign you tables to use the nest set method.

Comment: ok, sorry, i mean every previous records categoryid should match next one's parentcategoryId

Comment: I think we get it - but post up proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle anyway TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: ok, will try to do that.